# 'Database not found' after a lot of useage

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have found that when I do a lot of inserts into a local SQL CE database it seems to crash and stop accepting new requests. I am doing a rather lot of updates (However not that much) around 800 in a forloop, when I go to use fill a datatable with data at the same time (I am using delegates and worker items (`System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(ProcessRowObject), id);`),

In the worker is where it stops and I get `The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source =  ]`, even though when I create the connection I use

```
string cnnString = "Data Source=C:/Fastway/Database/Database.sdf";
SqlCeConnection Connection = new SqlCeConnection(cnnString);
```

When I execute the command I use:

```
DataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("", Connection);
var ret = new DataTable();
if (timeOut != 30)
{ //if the DBCon is part of a transaction that already has a timeout set, it keeps getting hosed here.
    db.DataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = timeOut;
}

if (ParameterConcat)
{
    query = QueryParametersToEmbeddedQuery(query, parameters);
}
else
{
    AddParameters(db.DataAdapter.SelectCommand, parameters);
}

db.DataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
try
{
    db.DataAdapter.Fill(ret);
}
catch (SqlCeException ex)
{
    throw new Exception("SQL query failed: " + query, ex);
}
return ret;
```

Soooo.... yeah. What can I do?

Comment: Hard-coding database paths like that is really dangerous; consider using `DataDirectory` if your database is read-only or `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` if it is not.

Comment: I originally did use then but then I came across this problem, so I started to try different things.

Comment: Are you sharing SqlCeConnection objects across threads? That is not supported as SqlCeConnection is not thread safe.

Comment: I guess I am, not the same object, but multiple objects, so multiple separate connections